# App Insights Log Files

Tags: log-files, azure-web-apps, application-insights

Application Insights is generating large log files for my web app daily and eating up space.  They mostly seem to contain the error pasted below.  Any idea how I can either resolve the issue or configure App Insights to stop generating these log files?

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AzureWebSites.TraceSource Error: 13 : Callback 'FrameworkSqlEventListener.OnEventWritten' failed for id = '0'. Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.ISupportSampling.set_SamplingPercentage(Double)'.
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.SamplingTelemetryProcessor.Process(ITelemetry item)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor.Process(ITelemetry item)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor.Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient.Track(ITelemetry telemetry)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.Implementation.FrameworkSqlProcessing.OnEndExecuteCallback(Int64 id, Boolean success, Boolean synchronous, Int32 sqlExceptionNumber)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.Implementation.FrameworkSqlEventListener.OnEndExecute(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.Implementation.FrameworkSqlEventListener.OnEventWritten(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
    ProcessId=15968
    DateTime=2017-01-23T11:21:55.8138906Z
```

Comment: When posting log/console samples, it helps readability to format them as code (see the [Markdown formatting help](https://serverfault.com/editing-help)) - there is a simple shortcut (ctrl+k) that will do the right thing to a selected block of text